# SPARQL Query to find someone's grandfather

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm just starting out learning SPARQL and I'm finding it a little difficult to navigate finding items and properties. Could anyone advise me on how to write a query which returns a person's grandfather? E.g. Tom Cruise's grandfather

Thanks!

Comment: depends on your knowledge of SPARQL in general. You should be able to use the syntax and write basic queries. The second problem is to understand the data. I mean, for Wikidata you have the advantage to look at example, e.g. Tom Cruise here https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q37079 . Check which data exists, then add the triple patterns. Indeed not for all relations there is a dedicated property. Like "grandFather", having it would be rather superflous given that it's obviously just the father of his mother or father. Last problem: the data must exist.

Comment: I'll give you once a Wikidata specific solution based on your example, the rest is up to you: `select ?parent ?parentLabel ?grandfather ?grandfatherLabel {
wd:Q37079 wdt:P22|wdt:P25 ?parent . OPTIONAL{?parent wdt:P22 ?grandfather}
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}`

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try one of these:

```
select * where {
    :personID :hasParent/:hasFather ?grandFather
}
select * where {
    :personID :hasFather/:hasFather ?grandFather_fatherSide
}
select * where {
    :personID :hasMother/:hasFather ?grandFather_motherSide
}
```

Legend:

- :personID = a specific ID
- :hasParent = relations a person with her father or mother
- :hasFather = relations a person with her father
- :hasMother = relations a person with her mother